# Host-file colums may be skipped only when copying into the server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, bcp

I want to create a xml file from my database with bcp.

The following code works in SQL Server 2008 but not in SQl Express 2005.

This is the code error:
`SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client] Host-file columns may be skipped only when copying into the Server`

These are Sql Express info:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express: 9.00.4035.00

Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC): 2000.085.1132.00 (xpsp.080413-0852)

Microsoft MSXML: 2.6 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0

Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702

Microsoft .NET Framework: 2.0.50727.3615

SO: 5.1.2600

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @dataExport AS DATETIME
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(8)

SET @FileName = 'c:\BackupSql\XMLOutput.xml'
SET @dataExport = '20110122'
SET @param = 'XXX'

DECLARE @SQLCmd VARCHAR(1800)

SELECT @SQLCmd = 'bcp ' + 
'"DECLARE @xml as xml; ' +
'DECLARE @text varchar(MAX); ' +             
'SET @xml = (select ' +
'(select ''' + convert(varchar(10), @dateExport, 112) + ''' as DateExport ' +
'FOR XML PATH (''DATA''), TYPE), ' + 
'(select ' +
    '(select Item as ITEM, cast(Quantity as int) as QTY, 
convert(decimal(10,6), Price) as PRICE, ''0.0'' as TOTAL, convert(varchar(10), DateInv, 112) as DATE from '+ DB_NAME() +'.dbo.ITEMS where (ITEM not like ''X-%'' and ITEM not like ''Y-%'') and DateInv = ''' + convert(varchar(10), @dateExport, 112) + ''' ' +
        'FOR XML PATH(''LINE''), TYPE) ' +
    'FOR XML PATH(''BODY''), TYPE) ' +
    'FOR XML PATH (''''), ' +
    'ROOT(''MYROOT''), TYPE); ' +
'SET @text = REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS varchar(max)), ''><'', ''>'' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ''<''); ' +
'SELECT @text" ' + 
' queryout ' +
@FileName + ' -c -T -S' + convert(varchar(128), serverproperty('servername')) --Trustedonnection e ANSI

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question then?!?!

Comment: This code doesn't work in sql express 2005 and I don't know why. It creates the xml file but is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

1) I created a stored procedure returning the xml content
2) I executed the former stored procedure in the bcp code.

Example code:
I found a workaround:

First I create a stored procedure returning the xml content and then I call it in the code for bcp.

Example code:

```
-- 1) --------------------------------------------

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XXX_TransformItemInXML]

    (     @dateExport as datetime     )
    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @xml xml;
    DECLARE @text varchar(MAX);

    SET @xml = (select
            (select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 112) as DATAESPORTAZIONE
            FOR XML PATH ('DATA'), TYPE),
                (select
                    (select Item as ITEM,
                         cast(Quantity as int) as QTY,
                     convert(decimal(10,6), Price) as PRICE,
                     '0.0' as TOTAL,
                    convert(varchar(10), DateInv, 112) as DATE
                from MYDB.dbo.Items
                where (Item not like 'x-%'
                    and Item not like 'Y-%')
                and DtaInv = @dateExport
                FOR XML PATH('LINE'), TYPE)
            FOR XML PATH('BODY'), TYPE)
            FOR XML PATH (''),
            ROOT('MYROOT'), TYPE)

    SET @text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

    SET @text = @text + REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS varchar(MAX)), '><', '>' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '<');

    SELECT @text

    END


-- END STORED PROCEDURE ----------------------------------------------------

-- BCP CODE ----------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1500)

    DECLARE @dataExport

    SET @dataExport = GETDATE()

    SET @fileName = 'C:\BackupSql\Output.xml'

    select @sqlCmd = 'bcp "exec ' + DB_NAME() + '.dbo.XXX_TransformItemInXML ''' + convert(varchar(10),@dateExport, 112) + ''' " queryout ' +
        @fileName +
        ' -c -T -S' + convert(nvarchar(128), serverproperty('servername')) -- Trusted connection e ANSI

    EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd

-- END BCP CODE ------------------------------------------------------------
```